# Don't remove notification badges from applications when swiping the notification from the status bar. Oreo 8.0

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, notification-icons, 8.0-oreo

On March 22, did the Samsung Galaxy S8/S8+ update. (For me and my colleagues at least.)

- Samsung Experience Version 9.0
- Android Version 8.0

One of the biggest features in Oreo 8.0 is the `Notification Channels`.
 ["Android Oreo will make you love notifications again".](https://www.androidcentral.com/android-o-and-notifications-everything-you-need-know)

Now it's possible to modify the notification badges to show numbers or dots, which you prefer yourself. Also notification snoozing and notification channels are some good features added with this update.

One annoying feature is: when you swipe away the notification from the status bar, does the notification badge remove too. Sure thing that you can snooze the notification for a certain amount of time. But also this option does remove the notification badge from your app untill the snoozing time has passed.

**TL;DR**
Is it possible to swipe a notification from the status bar, without removing the badge like it was possible in previous android versions?

Comment: Got the same issue with my S8. I keep on top of my notifications, but rely on the app markers as a longer term reminder. So now I have to cycle through certain apps to make sure I haven't missed something (having previously swiped notifications away). I'm sure some people might find this behaviour useful, but why not have it configurable??

Comment: This is a big UX issue with very low attention to my surprise.